# Inserting measurements through shell script and CURL failing

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8086/write?db=test' --data-binary $"inspec_reporting,profile=$profile success_control=$success_control,failure_control=$failure_control,skip_control=$skip_control,success_summary=$success_summary,failure_summary=$failure_summary,skip_summary=$skip_summary"
```

The above one is not working.

it is failing by adding special characters. When printed, not getting those special characters. Getting those special characters only with curl & influxDB.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: b60dd70d-ac82-11e9-9742-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse '$'inspec_reporting,profile=rhel7_enhanced_profile success_control=65,failure_control=72,skip_control=1,success_summary=252,failure_summary=211,skip_summary=1'': invalid boolean
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.6.2
X-Request-Id: b60dd70d-ac82-11e9-9742-000000000000
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2019 13:15:01 GMT
Content-Length: 302
```

> {"error":"unable to parse
>   '$'inspec_reporting,profile=rhel7_enhanced_profile
>   success_control=\u001b[38;5;41m65,failure_control=\u001b[38;5;9m72,skip_control=\u001b[38;5;247m1,success_summary=\u001b[38;5;41m252,failure_summary=\u001b[38;5;9m211,skip_summary=\u001b[38;5;247m1'':
>   invalid boolean"}

Comment: Please refer below url for information on my issue:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/14415

Comment: Thank first dollar doesn't look like it is in the correct position --data-binary $"

Comment: You will need to preprocess any spaces and special characters before parsing to escape the characters